# Converting date string with timezone to seconds in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I have a date string: "**13 December 2017**"

a time zone string: "**Asia/Kolkata**"

What is the way to get [**Epoch timestamp**](https://www.epochconverter.com/) **in seconds** in **Swift 4.0**?

Comment: If you have simplistic string as "13 December 2017" to convert to date, what is the place for timezone?

Comment: @Hexfire I need to generate epoch timestamp for that date string in that time zone irrespective of device's local timezone and send it to the server.

Comment: okay, I think below you have a good solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here the solution:

```
// your input
let dateStr = "13 December 2017"
let timeZoneStr = "Asia/Kolkata"

// building the formatter
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "d MMMM yyyy"
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: timeZoneStr)

// extracting the epoch
let date = formatter.date(from: dateStr) // Dec 13, 2017 at 3:30 AM
let epoch = date?.timeIntervalSince1970
print(epoch ?? "") // 1513103400
```

for information, this link: 
http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime
is an interesting source of date formatters

---

**Updated**:

Using Extension:

```
extension String {

  func epoch(dateFormat: String = "d MMMM yyyy", timeZone: String? = nil) -> TimeInterval? {
    // building the formatter
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
    if let timeZone = timeZone { formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: timeZone) }

    // extracting the epoch
    let date = formatter.date(from: self)
    return date?.timeIntervalSince1970
  }

}

"13 December 2017".epoch(timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata") // 1513103400
```

Comment: Tx. Updated with an extension :)